# Azure Data Factory vs Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, data-warehouse

Trying to self teach some ETL skills and need some help with the best way to do certain tasks.  I am trying to bring in data from our customer service platform - Freshdesk - into our SQL data warehouse.  We are a microsoft house and I have done somewhat similar tasks using Microsoft Azure Data Factory and Microsoft logic apps.  The logic apps are low/no code and a bit more intuitive so I am trying to use that now.  However, I feel like Data Factory might be the most efficient way to do this (although currently not 100% sure how to do it).  Any help or point in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: Generally, ADF is designed for bulk data movement, and Logic Apps are designed for application integration.  So there is significant overlap in functionality, but if you're moving lots of data, ADF is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 6):

**Azure Data Factory**

> If a large volume of data has to be moved from a data lake or an
> enterprise data warehouse (EDW) to Azure. For big data analytics, you
> may need to import large amounts of data into Azure from several
> sources. It is critical to achieve optimal performance and scalability
> in each circumstance.

Also, inside copy activity, you may consider boosting DTUs/Parallel copy choices, which can help you [increase copy performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance).

**Logic Apps**

When it comes to conducting repeating activities, modern data platform Logic Apps are fantastic. There are several connectors available, and it appears that the only limit to what you can accomplish with logic applications is your own imagination.

The [Event-Driven Architecture (EDA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory) paradigm involves the generation-

> Detection, consumption, and reaction of events. Users commonly need to
> activate pipelines based on storage account events, such as the
> arrival or deletion of a file in an Azure Blob Storage account, in
> data integration scenarios.

Hence, Azure Data Factory would be a better option over Azure  Logic Apps, but when it comes to repetitive tasks we could use Azure Logic Apps to orchestrate ETL via ADF. The decision of which to employ would be greatly influenced by the case at hand, and it would be worthwhile to explore combining ADF, Logic Apps, and other services such as Functions.